# How to synchronize a call from the asynchronous function in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, text-to-speech

I am working on my first app in Flutter, I have a bit of experience with Java and js, but I never worked with flutter before so sorry if my question will seem ridiculous to you.

The app is the voice assistant chatbot, and it is supposed to perform text to speech on each new message that customer receives, my problem is that since I am using firebase messaging all of the requests that I receive are in the asynchronous call, but I need to synchronize the access to the text to speech service otherwise I run into problem of having one text interrupt another.

This is what my code looks like at the moment:
Firebase messaging:

```
onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        return this.handleBotMessage(appState, message);
},
```

Method that desides how to handle each particular message:

```
Future handleBotMessage(
    Store<AppState> store,
    Map<String, dynamic> dataJson,
  ) {
      #logic that convert the message into json and extracts the message type

      if (type == MessageType.CHAT_MESSAGE) {
        return handleChatMessage(store, subtype, messageMap);
      }
  }
```

The method that handles text messages:

```
Future<dynamic> handleChatMessage(
    Store<AppState> store,
    MessageSubtype subtype,
    Map<String, dynamic> message,
  ) {
    #Text to speach is build as a singleton and this always returns the same instance
    TextToSpeech tts = TextToSpeech();
    if (subtype == MessageSubtype.TEXT) {
      TextMessage textMessage = TextMessage.fromJson(message);
      return tts
          .speak(textMessage.text)
          .then((result) => store.dispatch(NewBotMessageAction(textMessage)));
    } else if (subtype == MessageSubtype.QUICK_REPLY) {
      QuickReplyMessage qrMessage = QuickReplyMessage.fromJson(message);
      return tts
          .speak(qrMessage.text)
          .then((result) => store.dispatch(NewQrOptionsAction(qrMessage)));
    } else {
      throw new Exception('Unexpected message subtype!');
    }
  }
```

The method that actually performs the text to speech

```
Future<dynamic> speak(String text) async {
    return flutterTts.speak(text).then((resp) {
      ttsRunning = false;
      print(resp);
      return resp;
    }, onError: (obj, st) {
      ttsRunning = false;
      print(obj);
      print(st.toString());
    });
  }
```

Text to speech initialization

```
Future init() async {
    await flutterTts.setLanguage("en-US");
    var res = await flutterTts.isLanguageAvailable("en-US");
    print(res);
    return res;
  }
```

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tts

Comment: I think awaiting the `speak` method is not enough, you need to check the `flutterTts.setCompletionHandler` callback, maybe in combination with a queue if messages arrive too fast and interrupt each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution, the issue was as frank06 pointed out with the fact that flutter tts completes the future immediately rather than after the whole phrase was spoken.
So here is my solution, it is not perfect, but it works:

```
Completer completer;
Future<dynamic> speak(String text) {
    print('Started speeking');
    print(new DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
    if (TextToSpeech.lastRequest == null) {
      lastRequest = _executeSpeech(text);
    } else {
      lastRequest = lastRequest.then((resp) {
        return _executeSpeech(text);
      });
    }
    return lastRequest;
  }

  Future<dynamic> _executeSpeech(String text) {
    completer = Completer();
    flutterTts.speak(text).then((resp) {
      ttsRunning = false;
      print(resp);
      return resp;
    }, onError: (obj, st) {
      ttsRunning = false;
      print(obj);
      print(st.toString());
    });
    return completer.future;
  }


flutterTts.setCompletionHandler(() {
  print('Finished speeking');
  print(new DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
  ttsState = TtsState.stopped;
  completer.complete(ttsState);
});

flutterTts.setErrorHandler((msg) {
  ttsState = TtsState.stopped;
  completer.complete(ttsState);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want new messages interrupting those being spoken, you can queue them up. This way the new messages will wait for the current message to finish. Check out this approach:

[Queue of Future in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671529/queue-of-future-in-dart)